# Confirmation about android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Which type of eclipse version is suitable to work with android?

Comment: -1 for no research effort. As you can see, the answer is a simple documentation quote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Several types of Eclipse packages are available for each platform. For developing Android applications, we recommend that you install one of these packages:
>
> - Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
> - Eclipse Classic
> - Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers

http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html

Answer (score 1):

eclipse-jee-helios-SR2-win32

eclipse-java-indigo-SR1-win32

eclipse-jee-indigo-SR1-win32

....

& you can also configure Android In MyEclipse.